# HTML5 Video tag not showing on Iphone Safari. like the video isn't loading

Tags: python, html, django, video

I am using Django.
This is my code. The video is in mp4 format.

```
<video autoplay loop muted playsinline class="mt-5" style="width:100%;margin:0 auto;">
     <source src="{{ project.secondary_video_mobile.url }}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Is it something with apple devices? or any workaround for this issue?

Note: i tried adding controls and preload="metadata" and didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

checking the link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video, under browser compatibility for "Safari on iOS" its "Compatibility unknown". So adding any more attributes should not work considering the tag itself is not supported.